# Many of the mob's uses

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been playing Minecraft a lot, and I wondered what I can do with other mobs if I want to use them somehow.

What are the many helpful uses of all the mobs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Order from the Bedrock Edition inventory.

- **Sea Turtle:** A source for scutes, which can be used to make *Turtle Shells* and *Potions of the Turtle Master*.
- **Chicken:** A good food source because you can make fully automatic chicken farms within minutes with no redstone knowledge, produces eggs which are used to create cakes and pumpkin pie, and can also produce book and quills, arrows, and other craftable items.
- **Bee:** Makes honey, which you can then harvest to make honey blocks, which can help to make redstone contraptions, and Wax, useful for preserving copper blocks in a specific state

  - Bottles of honey can also cure poison.
  - They also speed up crop growth when pollinating
- **Cow:** A source for leather and food, as well as milk.
- **Pig:** A source of food and potential transportation.
- **Sheep:** A source of food, can be used for making beds, which is helpful for finding netherite.
- **Wolf:** Tamable and can help fight mobs.
- **Polar Bear:** There are chances of dropping fish from the mob.
- **Ocelot:** Tamable and usable to fend off creepers. If not to be a pet, then it's a good source of string.
- **Cat:** Tamable and usable to fend off creepers. If not to be a pet, then it's a good source of string.
- **Mooshroom:** A source of food.
- **Bat:** Bats have no use at the time of Update 1.16.
- **Parrot:** If not to be a pet, it's a source of feathers.
- **Rabbit:** A source of food and rabbit's foot (used for potions of leaping). Also drops Rabbit Hides, which will become useful for bundles in 1.17, and can be traded to Leatherworkers.
- **Llama:** Tamable and useful for storage and transportation. Also a source of Leather.
- **Horse:** Tamable and useful for transportation. Also a source of Leather.
- **Donkey:** Tamable and useful for storage and transportation.  Also a source of Leather.
- **Mule:** Tamable and useful for storage and transportation.  Also a source of Leather.
- **Skeleton Horse:** Tamable and useful for transportation, even underwater.
- **Zombie Horse:** Tamable and useful for transportation.
- **Tropical Fish:** A source of food and useful for taming cats.
- **Cod:** A source of food and useful for taming cats.
- **Pufferfish:** A minimal weapon to poison other entities, and used to make a Potion of Water Breathing.
- **Salmon:** A source of food and useful for taming cats.
- **Dolphin:** Makes you swim faster and helps you find buried treasures.
- **Panda:** Too much bamboo? They can take it all. Can also create a very inefficient slime farm.
- **Fox:** Can store one item and a source of rabbit's foot (used for potions of leaping).
- **Creeper:** A source for gunpowder, and music discs when shot by a skeleton.
- **Enderman:** Source for enderpearls, which are extremely helpful.
- **Silverfish:** A source for XP.
- **Skeleton:** A source for arrows, bows, and bones, which then can be used for wolf taming or bone meal.
- **Wither Skeleton:** A source for wither skulls, which can be used to spawn a wither. Can also be used as a source of coal.
- **Stray:** A source for arrows, bows, and bones, which then can be used for wolf taming or bone meal. Can be used to get Arrows of Slowness.
- **Slime:** A source for slime, which can be used for neglecting fall damage and redstone contraptions.
- **Spider:** A source of string and spider eyes, useful for potions.
- **Zombie:** Source of rotten flesh, good for wolves or trading. Also has a chance to drop potatoes or carrots.
- **Zombified Piglin:** There are chances of it dropping gold and weapons.
- **Husk:** Source of rotten flesh, good for wolves or trading.
- **Drowned:** A source of meat for wolves and tridents, and has chances of dropping other items such as Nautilus Shells, which are used to create Conduits.
- **Squid:** A source of ink sacs, useful for book and quills.
- **Cave Spider:** A source of string and spider eyes, useful for potions.
- **Witch:** Drops random potion components.
- **Guardian:** There are chances of it dropping either cod or prismarine.
- **Elder Guardian:** Has chances of dropping fish, prismarine, and wet sponges, and helps inflict mining fatigue.
- **Endermite:** Can be used for XP farming or to create an Enderman farm.
- **Magma Cube:** Drops magma cream, helps make Potions of Fire Resistance.
- **Strider:** A source for string and helps with nether transportation.
- **Hoglin:** A source of food.
- **Piglin:** You can barter with them, dropping certain items, including ender pearls.
- **Zoglin:** Source of rotten flesh, good for wolves or trading.
- **Piglin Brute:** Can drop golden axes, which then can be used with Unbreaking and Mending to cut down trees faster.
- **Ghast:** A source of ghast tears, which can be used for Potions of Regeneration. Can also drop gunpowder.
- **Blaze:** A source of blaze rods, which helps to get to strongholds.
- **Shulker:** A source for shulker shells, which can be used for shulker boxes.
- **Vindicator:** Drops emeralds, which can be used for trading, and drops others in Bedrock Edition.
- **Evoker:** Drops the Totem of Undying.
- **Vex:** Can be used for XP farming.
- **Villager:** Useful for trades.
- **Wandering Trader:** Useful for trades.
- **Zombie Villager:** Can be cured and useful for trades.
- **Phantom:** Drops phantom membranes, which can be used to repair elytras.
- **Pillager:** Drops emeralds, which can be used for trading, and drops others in Bedrock Edition.
- **Ravager:** A source for saddles.
- **Wither:** Drops the nether star, which can make a beacon, giving different effects.
- **Ender Dragon:** Gets you to complete the game, and also helps for XP farming if it was re-summoned.

Comment: Recent snapshot had drowned give copper ingots instead of gold, meaning copper is renewable.

Comment: Pandas can be used to make an extremely inefficient [slime farm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-xu-wIg_P0); in peaceful mode they are still a more efficient source of slime than wandering traders.

Comment: You know you guys can update this answer, right?

Answer (score 2):

Specialized mob uses for farms:

- **Hoglin:** They are unique in that they are hostile mobs, so can spawn much more than passive mobs, while also producing one of the best food sources in the game. Once you setup an extremely minimal hoglin farm on a server, the food produced could feed hundreds of players.
- **Skeleton:** Skeletons are automatically attacked by player owned wolves, making fully automatic XP farms possible. Bows may be useful for the annoying crafting of dispensers.
- **Piglins:** can be traded with to obtain renewable materials.
- **Zombie Piglins:** Due to their aggro mechanic, can also be used to create fully automatic XP farms. Useful for gold farms for piglin bartering.
- **Snow Golem:** Leaves trails of snow wherever they go in cold biomes, leading to extremely fast snow farms. Useful for provoking other mobs, as they shoot snowballs towards hostile mobs on their own.
- **Iron Golem:** Effective defense, can be used to kill mobs as long as they are protected from getting hurt, and obvious use in iron farms, one of the most useful farms in the game.
- **Witch:** Produces many useful drops including gunpowder, glass bottles, redstone, and sugar.

Comment: suggestion: add how the chicken can be used to create simple compact automatic cooked chicken and feather farms